# different dates format in one string column, need to align to one format in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

let's that I have an column which holds different type of dates format i.e.

```
Date
01.09.2021 00:19:03
01.09.2021 04:00:59
01.09.2021 12:04:02
01.09.2021 19:17:16
01.09.2021 23:59:37
11/18/2020 2:20:07 AM
11/18/2020 7:36:47 AM
11/18/2021 11:49:05 AM
11/18/2021 1:20:21 PM
11/18/2021 6:21:21 PM
```

and now I need to update all values to the second format and keep string data type. Is there any optimal way to do that? Table is pretty big and holds almost ~50 mln records.

Thank you for any help and regards!

Comment: How do you know if `01.09.2021` is 1st septemeber or 9th January?

Comment: Do this work to still keep the string data type is not so logic.

Comment: The problem here is that you designed a table with a `varchar` column to store date and time data; there are 6 date and time data types, and 6 of them are more than appropriate for the above data. Unfortunately, apart from the ones which are for the "18th month" (I'm English, so we read dd/MM/yyyy) your other dates have lost all meaning, as you don't know if they're for January or September. You'll need to spend time fixing the values you know for sure are correct, `NULL` the rest, and then fix your design..

Comment: That comment, @LeandroBardelli , makes no sense, I am afraid.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not the designer for this table, but I need to fix this now.. :( 01.09.2021 is 1st September for sure. I just verified all data, and there are only those two formats. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Ohhh, that's an ugly set of requirements, and I definitely empathize with you on it. At that sort of scale, I'll strongly advise you not to do that sort of updating "online" in your actual, production table. My recommendation is to create a new table with the correct datatype and use an ETL tool to transform the strings to the desired format while writing them to the new table. Validate that all your rows correctly transferred, then cut over to the new table by renaming the improper one, then rename the new one to the appropriate name

Comment: Yep, but it's not so easy because, based on this table, there are a set of other ETL processes which use this data, transform, and so on, and right now, it does not work because of these different data formats.. I need to fix this somehow and request a change for that in the near future.. thank for any help!

Comment: @Larnu is was not my inttention to ofend, what I try to say is that is a lot of work to "fix" the data in that column and then save it as varchar instead make a new column, keeping the door open to errors again.

Comment: @anders1990 do you know how many "kind" of formats do you have?

Comment: @Leandro I believe that it's only those two above, I do not see any others

Comment: @anders1990 are you working with mysql, oracle, sql server, etc?

Comment: It *is* a lot of work, yes @anders1990 . Best get started now, so that your data doesn't get even worse.

Comment: it's SQL server, so tsql will be right here. @Larnu I totally agree with you.

Comment: @anders1990 with the additional details you've shared in comments, you have a full-blown project on your hands. I believe you're going to benefit from the sort of approach I outlined previously, with the added steps of modifying those consuming jobs as versioned copies in parallel to the current ones and test, test, test to be sure you're getting the results you expect

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  Old = dt,
  New = CAST(f.Dt AS DATETIME)
FROM   (VALUES('01.09.2021 00:19:03'),
('01.09.2021 04:00:59'),
('01.09.2021 12:04:02'),
('01.09.2021 19:17:16'),
('01.09.2021 23:59:37'),
('11/18/2020 2:20:07 AM'),
('11/18/2020 7:36:47 AM'),
('11/18/2021 11:49:05 AM'),
('11/18/2021 1:20:21 PM'),
('11/18/2021 6:21:21 PM')) AS f(Dt);
```

**Returns:**

```
Old                    New
---------------------- -----------------------
01.09.2021 00:19:03    2021-01-09 00:19:03.000
01.09.2021 04:00:59    2021-01-09 04:00:59.000
01.09.2021 12:04:02    2021-01-09 12:04:02.000
01.09.2021 19:17:16    2021-01-09 19:17:16.000
01.09.2021 23:59:37    2021-01-09 23:59:37.000
11/18/2020 2:20:07 AM  2020-11-18 02:20:07.000
11/18/2020 7:36:47 AM  2020-11-18 07:36:47.000
11/18/2021 11:49:05 AM 2021-11-18 11:49:05.000
11/18/2021 1:20:21 PM  2021-11-18 13:20:21.000
11/18/2021 6:21:21 PM  2021-11-18 18:21:21.000
```

Comment: it's not the case I would like to get the second format as an result, but thank you for your answer